# NSMutableArray with memory leak

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ipad

I am using following code to create NSMutableArray. When I run the same in “Profile” mode, it is showing a memory leakage.

SampleArray.h

```
@interface SampleArray: NSObject {
}
@property (assign, retain) NSMutableArray *array;
@end
```

SampleArray.m

```
#import "SampleArray.h"
@implementation SampleArray
@synthesize array;
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    self.array =[ [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.array release];
}
@end
```

When I am using autorelease, then I can’t able to access the same in other function or method and return null value. Please help me to find the issue.

Comment: you can't use assign and retain at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

releasing this array in viewWilLDisappear is not a good idea, you should release in the dealloc function. You should worry about over-releasing this item and causing a program crash since viewWilLDisappear may get called multiple times during the lifetime of this ViewController.

Anyhow, you are double retaining the item beacuse your property has a retain on it (and make it nonatomic, not assign), add an autorelease to your alloc/init:

```
self.array =[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

and move

```
[array release];
```

to your dealloc function.  Or convert to ARC and don't worry any longer...

Comment: I released the array in dealloc method and still showing memory leak. any guess?

Comment: you can NSLog the retainCount property of your object if you're unsure.  When dealloc is called, it should be = 1

Comment: I am getting retainCount 2 after initialize and not able to get the retainCount in dealloc method. It is throwing error message.

Comment: NEVER use the retainCount property.  Ever.  Ever Ever.  Horrible advice.  See http://www.whentouseretaincount.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it to (nonatomic, retain), then autoreleasing.

Comment: sorry, i am using (nonatomic, retain)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm assuming that you are using

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *array;
```

use this

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    array =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [array release];
}
```

I will recommend you to use dealloc instead of `viewWillDisappear`

```
-(void) dealloc {
    [array release];
    [super dealloc];
 }
```

---

Explanation of your code

```
   -(void) viewDidLoad {
        // here you are allocating a mutable array thus retain count becomes one
        // then you are assigning it to the property which is retain and thus retains it
        // making the retain count 2
        self.array =[ [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    -(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
        // here you are releasing it so its retain count becomes 1 from 2
        // thus shows memory leak
        [self.array release];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to handle memory de-allocation in your -dealloc() and set your array to nil to be more secure in your -viewDidUnload()

so it will be:

```
-(void) viewDidUnload 
{
    self.array = nil;
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    [array release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

and like other people said, declare your  property as **(nonatomic, retain)** instead of (assign, retain)